# Show My Current Location on Emulator when MapsActivity is Started

Tags: android, google-maps, currentlocation

Given Below is my Code showing Current Location in which mLastLocation toasted is null and does not show my current location and doesn't add any marker to it.

```
@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,       android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=                 PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "onConnected Method"+String.valueOf(mGoogleApiCLient.isConnected()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiCLient);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Currrrrrrrent"+mLastLocation, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (mLastLocation!=null)
    {
        latLng=new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(),mLastLocation.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions=new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Current Location");
        mCurrLocation=mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    }
    mLocationRequest=new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(5000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(3000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiCLient,mLocat ionRequest,this);

}
```

Comment: Did you make sure to set the coordinates in the emulator settings?

Comment: @SammyT yeah Made changes